# Add new field to a collection based on other fields

Tags: mongodb, pipeline

"MongoDB version: 4.2
OS: OSX

I have the following document in the Home collection:

```
{
    "_id" : "xxxx",
    "name" : "home1",
    "homeName" : "home1",
    "allowAdminActions" : true,
    "_created_at" : ISODate("2020-02-07T14:55:06.819Z"),
    "_updated_at" : ISODate("2020-02-07T14:55:12.356Z"),
    "_p_Owner" : "xxxxx",
    "allowUpdate" : false,
    "devicesConfig" : {
        "hello" : 1,
        "deviceConfig" : {
            "data" : [
                {
                    "type" : "CommunicationConfig",
                    "wifiName" : "wifitest",
                    "wifiPassword" : "wifipassword"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Then I would like to create a field called `wifiName` extrapolated from the `devicesConfig` field:

```
db.Home.update(
    {},
    [
        {"$project": {"connConfig": {$arrayElemAt: ["$devicesConfig.deviceConfig.data", 0]}}},
        {"$set":  {"wifiName": "$connConfig.wifiName"}}
    ],
    false,
    true
)
```

The expected results would be:

```
{
    "_id" : "xxxx",
    "name" : "home1",
    "homeName" : "home1",
    "allowAdminActions" : true,
    "_created_at" : ISODate("2020-02-07T14:55:06.819Z"),
    "_updated_at" : ISODate("2020-02-07T14:55:12.356Z"),
    "_p_Owner" : "xxxx",
    "allowUpdate" : false,
    "devicesConfig" : {
        "hello" : 1,
        "deviceConfig" : {
            "data" : [
                {
                    "type" : "CommunicationConfig",
                    "wifiName" : "wifitest",
                    "wifiPassword" : "wifipassword"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "wifiName" : "wifitest"
}
```

The actual result:

```
{
    "_id" : "xxxxx",
    "connConfig" : {
        "type" : "CommunicationConfig",
        "wifiName" : "testwifi",
        "wifiPassword" : "testpassword"
    },
    "wifiName" : "testwifi"
}
```

How to avoid that the `update` operation deletes all other, non-specified, fields?

Thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) with combination of [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html) :

```
db.Home.update(
    {},
    [
        {"$addFields": {"connConfig": {$arrayElemAt: ["$devicesConfig.deviceConfig.data", 0]}}},
        {"$set":  {"wifiName": "$connConfig.wifiName"}},
        {'$project' : {'connConfig': 0}}
    ],
    false,
    true
)
```